# Error Message: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've searched the internet, all previous answers said that a semicolon is missing. That's not the problem. What else can cause this error? In the third site, several people asked this question but this scenario is different.

Error is > **Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expecte**d

```
 public partial class SeenSMS : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    //temp sql connection
    //public SqlConnection mycon;
    SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ASOFT20\MAMUT;Initial   Catalog=ViltraNew;UserID=sa;Password=sa123");


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] msg_arr = Request.QueryString["arr"].Split('|');

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string Moose = Request.QueryString[1];
        }

        if (msg_arr != null)
        {
            if ((msg_arr.Length == 3) && (msg_arr[1].ToLower() == "slett"))

            {
                int Hours = Convert.ToInt32(msg_arr[2]);

                if (Hours > 0)
                {   
                    string username = msg_arr[0];

                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) as count  FROM Animal Where Hours=@Hours", mycon);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours",Hours);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if(reader.HasRows)
                        {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                             // int number = Convert.ToInt32(con.ExecuteReader());
                            int number = Convert.ToInt32(reader["count"]);

                        }
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                }
             //   if( number == 0)
               // {
                   // Response.Write("Improper Plain Summaries.");
              //  }
             //   else
                {

                }


                }
            }


        }

  public  bool number { get; set; }
  public  object Hours { get; set; }}



   // public System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Moose { get; set; }



  //  public string Value { get; set; }

  //  public object msg_arr { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Comment: you have too many '}" from a first look

Comment: ***I*** get lost in the number of closing braces, no wonder the compiler does too. Stuff like this wouldn’t happen with proper code formatting.

Comment: This question is clearly helping some future visitors -- someone even favorited it. It's hard to predict what will help a newbie (or not so newbie) in the future.

Comment: I just had this error and went through all my {} and semi-colons and couldn't find anything wrong.  It was driving me crazy.  It turned out that VS Code was just confused.  I closed it and re-opened, and the problem mysteriously vanished.

Comment: Me, same problem today. Visual Studio Community 2019 was apparently confused. Closed VS and restarted it, and voila no errors.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This line:

```
public  object Hours { get; set; }}
```

Your have a redundand `}` at the end

Answer (score 8):

You have extra brackets in Hours property;

```
public  object Hours { get; set; }}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have System.Web referenced
2. Get rid of the two } at the end.