# An inheritance code in Visual C#

Tags: c#

I have the follwoing code which I don't understand where is my mistake?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   class Program
     {
      public class Animal
      {
        public virtual void Greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I'm some sort of animal!");
        }
    }
    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void Greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I'm a dog!");
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't get compiled, I get the following errors:
On Line 24 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
and on Line 6 } is expected

I don't understand what did I do wrong, can you help me?
Thanks.
I compiled this in Visual Studio 2015, if it matters.

BTW, I got part of this code from this tutorial:
http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/inheritance/

Comment: Offtopic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: check if your brackets and curly braces are closed properly. have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976243/error-message-type-or-namespace-definition-or-end-of-file-expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a confusion about scopes. You defined a class in a method which is not applicable, you should define classes under namespace scope.

It should be this way (This is a pseudo code)

```
 namespace YourNamespace
 ...class Program
 .... public class animal
 .... public class dog : animal
 .... static void main
```

Comment: What to write inside the static void main(string[] args){}?

Comment: You want to create an instance of Dog or Animal, and call its Greet function. Like this: `Dog dog = new Dog(); dog.Greet();`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a class within a method body, which is what happens here:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   class Program
     {
```

Instead you need to place the code for your `Main()` method within the `Program` class:

```
class Program
{ // This brace marks the beginning of the Program class

    static void Main(string[] args) // This is a method defined WITHIN Program class
    { // The brace marks the beginning of the Main method
       ....
    } // This brace marks the end of the Main method

} // This brace closes the Program class
```