# Unity C# Error: "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried many times to fix this without success. Whenever I close my function on line 14 (`public void FrenchButton ()`), it thinks it closes `public class LanguageMenuScript : MonoBehaviour`. How can I fix this?

The code is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LanguageMenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text languageTitleText;

    public void FrenchButton()
    {
        public string language = "French";
    }


    void Start (){
        Text.text = Language;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (language == "French")
        {
            languageTitleText.text = "Langue";
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: (Note: I am quite new to both Unity and C#)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Message: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976243/error-message-type-or-namespace-definition-or-end-of-file-expected)

Comment: I've checked that post - I don't have any extra brackets that I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **public string language = "French";** inside a function. You can't have a access modifier inside a function and you cant access variables declared inside a function from outside. What you want to do there is declare it next to languageTitleText inside the class scope. you can then assign a value in your FrenchButton function if you want -> language = "French"; for instance.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Use a proper internationalization package. You are making yourself a lot more work than you'd like using your current approach. This concept (usually using `I18n`) and its application to Unity [is discussed here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1245242/best-practice-to-internationalizei18n-a-unity-proj.html).

## Solution 2: Fixing your code

You probably want to use an `enum`, like below. Once you have changed the script, check out the component in the inspector. You can now choose from the given set of languages defined in your enum.

[Here is an official tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enumerations) on how to use `enum`s in Unity.

Code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public enum Language {
  French: 1,
  German: 2,
  English: 3
}

public class LanguageMenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text languageTitleText;
    public Language language = Language.French;

    void Start (){
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (language == Language.French)
        {
            languageTitleText.text = "Langue";
        }
        else if (language == Language.German) 
        {
            languageTitleText.text = "Sprache";
        }
        else
        {
          // take English as default
          languageTitleText.text = "Language";
        }
    }
}
```