# Syntax errors but I am unable to get them fixed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am messing arround with Unity and c# for the first time, and I fail to see what is the compiling telling me

I have checked links such as [Error Message: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976243/error-message-type-or-namespace-definition-or-end-of-file-expected) and https://answers.unity.com/questions/1255548/-expected-type-or-namespace-definition-or-end-of-f.html, they are simple examples but when I compare side to side I can't find the syntax error (I understand there are many things wrong in the code but right now I cannot keep moving forward because of the syntax).

Also, the unity version is unity 2019.3.13F1

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mouselook1 : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform Playerbody;
    float xRotation = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.DeltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.DeltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        Transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        PlayerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

And this is the console error:

[image: And this is the console error]

Comment: @RufusL I tried after you suggested, but I think vasmos is on the right track, I was debugging the wrong file, sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors are on Movement.cs not MouseLook1.cs

Comment: Nowhere has the OP posted the name of the `.cs` file...

Comment: Its on the console error Assets/Movement.cs

Comment: I might simply delete this whole thing out of embarrasment... You are right. I was looking in the wrong file because originally I had two and both equally wrong. I have now fixed

Comment: No need to be embarrassed we all get tunnel vision in the wrong areas sometimes